# Making a Game With Arduino and Processing

Tags: arduino, processing

I am trying to form a two player game which requires an audio reflex to a visual. by using littebits sound trigger for sound input and littbits arduino to connect it to the computer. But I am new to this and don't know how to connect arduino to processing and use the input from sound trigger to effect the score when a black square appears.

here is my code in processing and a sample arduino code I have taken from littlebits website and tried to modify a little.

thanks in advance!

`float dice;`

```
int playerOne = 0; //player 1 score (left paddle)                              
int playerTwo = 0; //player 2 score (right paddle)                             
boolean oneWins = false;                                                       
boolean twoWins = false;                                                       

void setup(){                                                                  
    size(500, 500);                                                            
    smooth();                                                                  
    noStroke();                                                                
    frameRate(2.5);                                                            
}                                                                              

void draw() {                                                                  

    background(255);                                                           
    showGUI();                                                                 
    dice = random(0, 3);                                                       

    if (dice < 1.000001 && dice > 0.1){                                        
        fill ((0), (255), (0));                                                
        ellipse (250,250,100,100);                                             
    } else if (dice < 2.000001 && dice > 1.000001){                            
        rectMode(RADIUS);                                                      
        fill ((255), (0), (0));                                                
        rect (250,250,50,50);                                                  
    } else if (dice < 3.000000 && dice > 1.000000){                            
        rectMode(RADIUS);                                                      
        fill ((0), (0), (255));                                                
        rect (250,250,50,50);                                                  
    } else if (dice < 0.1){                                                    
        rectMode(RADIUS);                                                      
        fill(0);                                                               
        rect(250,250,50,50);                                                   
    }                                                                          
}                                                                              
----------arduino------                                                        

void setup() {                                                                 
    Serial.begin(9600); //Establish rate of Serial communication               
    establishContact(); //See function below                                   
}                                                                              

void loop() {                                                                  
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {                                              
        int inByte = Serial.read();                                            
        int leftTrigger = analogRead(A0);                                      

        Serial.print(leftTrigger, DEC);                                        
        Serial.print(",");                                                     

        int rightTrigger = analogRead(A1);                                     
        Serial.println(rightTrigger, DEC);                                     
    }                                                                          
}                                                                              

void establishContact() {                                                      

    while (Serial.available() <= 0) {                                          
        Serial.println("hello");                                               
        delay(300);                                                            
    }                                                                          
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions other than by pointing you to google. Instead, try asking questions in the form of "I tried to do X, expected Y, but got Z instead.. what's going on?" and posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can actually run.

Comment: You need to remember which form is displayed, you can use `dice` but an `enum` could be nicer.  Read this to find example arround sound http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Clap-Sensitive-Light-Control-The-Clapper/ . And if you have a square and a _clap_ increase score

Answer (score 0):

You need two pieces of code for this to work: one on the Arduino that sends commands, and one for Processing to receive and parse those commands.

I haven't used the littlebits modules, but here's a button example from [this very detailed tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/electronics/).

Arduino code:

```
int switchPin = 4;               // switch connected to pin 4 

void setup() { 
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);     // set pin 0 as an input 
  Serial.begin(9600);            // start serial communication at 9600bps 
} 

void loop() { 
  if (digitalRead(switchPin) == HIGH) {  // if switch is ON, 
    Serial.print(1, BYTE);               // send 1 to Processing
  } else {                               // if the switch is not ON,
    Serial.print(0, BYTE);               // send 0 to Processing 
  } 
  delay(100);                            // wait 100 milliseconds 
}
```

And the matching Processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*; 

Serial port;            // create object from Serial class 
int val;                // data received from the serial port 

void setup() { 
  size(200, 200); 
  frameRate(10); 

  // open the port that the board is connected to
  // and use the same speed (9600bps) 
  port = new Serial(this, 9600); 
} 

void draw() { 
  if (0 < port.available()) {        // if data is available,
    val = port.read();               // read it and store it in val
  } 
  background(255);                   // set background to white
  if (val == 0)  {                   // if the serial value is 0,
    fill(0);                         // set fill to black
  } else {                           // if the serial value is not 0,
    fill(204);                       // set fill to light gray
  } 
  rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
```

Notice that the Arduino sends a value that Processing looks for and interprets. You can also look at the `PhysicalPixel` example from the Arduino IDE for an example on sending data from Processing to Arduino.